# VBA code not sorting dates properly (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that tracks items and dates. Each item has a corresponding date associated with it:

Screenshot showing conditional formatting:
[image: Screenshot showing conditional formatting]

If the date is equal to or less than 100 days from the present date, the date cell is highlighted green, using this conditional formatting formula:

```
=TODAY()-C3:C12<120
```

If the date is greater than 100 days from the present date, the cell is highlighted red, using this conditional formatting formula:

```
=TODAY()-C3:C12>=120
```

In addition, all rows are sorted by date, in ascending order, and blank date cells produce no conditional formatting:

```
=ISBLANK(C3:C12)=TRUE
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that, when a date is updated for a particular item, all the rows need to be dynamically rearranged into the new ascending date order using VBA code.

In the screenshot, you'll notice that Item 6 is out of place. Its entire row should automatically be moved into the correct sequence by date order, by the macro.

I have tried to incorporate the following script that I found online. Unfortunately, some very strange behavior ensued and my rows were rearranged in a way that I could not properly understand. The header gets moved by the macro below everything else, no matter what I do!

Can anyone see what's wrong with this VBA code? It makes an absolute mess of my data as soon as I update any dates.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Range("C3").Sort Key1:=Range("C12"), _
  Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
  OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

"You haven't provided a link to the script"

Link to script:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3655-excel-auto-sort-by-date.html

"...and more importantly told us what the random script was actually supposed to do"

The script is supposed to auto sort dates, when entered or modified, as can be inferred from:

"The problem I am trying to solve is that, when a date is updated for a particular item, *all the rows need to be dynamically rearranged into the new ascending date order using VBA code*."

... and:

"*Its entire row should automatically be moved into the correct sequence by date order, by the macro*."

Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough that the purpose of this script is to dynamically arrange dates as they are modified.

Here is what happens when a new date is added; the header gets moved below the data:

[Header gets sorted along with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlVEC.png)

Can anyone see why the header would be moved below the data?

Comment: We are not going to debug some random script you found online for you. You haven't provided a link to the script and more importantly told us what the random script was actually supposed to do and **exactly** what goes wrong when you try to use it.

Comment: David, I have added more information to the question. Please remove your down vote and unlock the question so that people with experience in troubleshooting VBA scripts can actually answer. It's not too broad. I ask a specific question and provide ample context. Please give people a chance to answer.

Comment: Don't worry. I ended up just solving my own problem while struggling to get my question unlocked. For anyone else who runs into a similar issue with unexpected Excel sorting behaviour: please see this useful resource: https://software-solutions-online.com/use-vba-range-sort-method/ The "random" script works perfectly well now.

Comment: Sorry, but even with the edit, your question doesn't seem to be answerable.  It is not clear what is in your actual spreadsheet, exactly how you tried to adapt the code you found to your spreadsheet, what you want the code to do in your spreadsheet (what the result should look like), and what it is or isn't doing.  There are many ways in which you might be incorrectly adapting the code to your situation.  Just some obvious ones: volatile dates, conditional formatting, or expecting the script to do something different than it's designed to do.  Kudos if you solved it on your own.

Comment: @wrecclesham, your code needs few corrections, also you have missed one basic issue that, you want to Sort only Date Column, since reorder of dates principally needs related order to Items also !! Or if you only need Dates to be reshuffled on each new entry then you must specify it .

Comment: Part of my frustration is that they have changed the rules of this site to prevent new users from having in-line images. I can upload my screenshots and paste the Imgur links, but the readability just isn't the same as having all my images properly in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by modifying the range values as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("B3:C12").Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), _
  Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
  OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

I had initially only referenced a single cell, rather than a range of cells, so the script ended up sorting every row, including the header. It now works as intended.

My question was answerable and this was the answer.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! I've edited your posts to show the pictures. I'm sure you'll quickly get enough reputation to be able to post pictures.